# Drupal display views block when a referenced filter from another view is used

Tags: drupal-7, view, drupal-contextual-filters

I have a page view(1) that filters a content type by diferent field results, one of them is a referenced entity and I'd like to display it's whole content whenever a filter by this referenced field is used.

I've created a block view(2) that displays the referenced entity and tried to use contextual filters to display it only in the results view page when it is used aa a filter but I haven't find the correct way to do this

I've tried to provide a default value for the content id from the url but I the field value responds to target_id, I've also tried to use php with something like: echo ($_GET['field_nameofthefield_target_id']) but it didn't work out

Could anyone help me with this please?

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: here's the results page where the block should be displayed filtered by field_ponente_target_id=12 http://nobelbiocareformacion.com/en/buscador?field_fecha_value%5Bvalue%5D%5Bmonth%5D=3&field_fecha_value%5Bvalue%5D%5Byear%5D=2014&field_provincia_tid=All&field_ponente_target_id=12&term_node_tid_depth_i18n=All&keys=